# convexity of a relatively open subset of a compact set

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

I'm struggling  with the following problem: it seems to be true but I'm not able to prove it!
Let $C$ be a compact convex subset of a locally convex metric vector space and $\hat{C}$ be a relatively open subset of $C$, i.e. there exists an open set $\Omega$ such that $\hat{C}=C\cap\Omega$.
Clearly if $\Omega$ is convex then $\hat{C}$ is also convex; is the converse true? I mean, if I assume that $\hat{C}$ is convex, can I suppose the existence of an open and convex set $\Omega$ such that $\hat{C}=C\cap \Omega$?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Let $x \in \hat C$, then there exists an open ball $B$ about $x$ with maximal radius such that $B \cap C \subseteq \hat C$. Now take the union of all these balls and show that it is convex.

Comment: @HansEngler Are you sure this works? I don't find it convincing.

Comment: @HansEngler Thank you for your fast reply. 
Unfortunately take the square $C=[-2,2]\times[0,4]$ and $\hat{C}=\{(x,y)\in (-2,2)\times[0,2):x<y\}$ (that is open in $C$).
Then the union of all the proposed balls is the open set $\hat{C}\cup B((-1,0);1)$ which is not convex (where $B((-1,0);1)$ is the open ball with center at $(-1,0)$ and radius $1$)

Comment: On Hilbert spaces, the *Hilbert projection theorem* might prove to be useful for this problem

Comment: Okay, the *weaker* case when $C = \hat{C}$ and the ambient vector space is a Hilbert space can easily be solved. In this case, you can take $\Omega$ to be the open set of points with distance from $C$ less then some fixed positive constant and use the projection theorem to deduce the result.

Comment: @GiulioMarchi You should write an official answer to your own question and accept it (https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). This will clear the question from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that it seemed to be true but, after a week, I have found a counterexample!
Take the square $C=[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$  and the open set $\Omega=A\cup B$ where $A=(-2,2)\times(-2,2)$ and $B=(-1,1)\times\mathbb{R}$. Then $\hat{C}=A\cup[(-1,1)\times\{\pm 2\}]$ is convex and open in $C$  but clearly there is no open and convex set $\Omega'$ such that $\hat{C}=C\cap\Omega'$.